# HTML 2 CSS files

Tags: html, css

First sorry for my bad English..

I'm stuck in small problem in HTML commands..

the problem is, I have 2 CSS command that have same name ( I don't know how to explain clearly )

[Secondary Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRU85.png)

[Primary Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMsYJ.png)

Is there any way to spreat them, My tutor said to me : use   
but I didn't understand the concept clearly..

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't use images, update question with relevant CSS commands and try to explain what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You want separate ul styling for your primary navigation and secondary navigation.

Add class="primary" or class="secondary" to your ul tags.

Follow all the styles for each with `.classname`:

`ul .primary {
 }`

`ul .secondary {
 }`

Comment: It should've been ul assessed then class ?